# Excel: Averaging 2 columns with a PivotTable

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, average

Data example:

| Year | Activity | L | H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019 | x | 5 | 9 |
| 2015 | z | 1 | 0 |
| 2015 | x | 5 | 4 |
| 2020 | z | 4 | 5 |
| 2020 | y | 7 | 3 |

Using a pivot table, I can average L by "Activity" and average by "Activity" looks like:

| Activity | L | H |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | 5 | 6.5 |
| Y | 7 | 3 |
| Z | 2.5 | 2.5 |

What I need to is to average by Activity for the whole year (where L + H).  I tried a "calculated field" but it only provides "1" across the activities, using this formula:

```
= (SUM('L $')+SUM('H $'))/COUNT(Activity)
```

And I tried

```
= ('L $'+'H $')/COUNT(Activity)
```

I can sum L + H by activity in the pivot, and I can do a count of activities in the pivot.  However, when I attempt to make a calculated equation, the count of activities is not a FIELD option to use in the formula (avg =sum / count).

How can I calculate in a pivot table the average for the whole year (L+H) by activity?

Comment: Please show an example of your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to my following steps, any misunderstanding, please let us know.

Step 1

Select the range of all data > right click > Get Data from Table/Range, then you would import data into Power Query as a table.

Step 2

Click Add Column > Custom Column > Insert H, type "+" and insert L. You may also enter the name for new column, then click OK.

[image]

Step 3

Click File > Close & Load to > PivotTable report.

Step 4

Drag the fields into different areas as your needs. The following image is my example.

[image]

Comment: I don't know software you are using, but MS Excel 2016 does not have "Close & Load to "

Comment: I am using the [Power Query](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/introduction-to-microsoft-power-query-for-excel-6e92e2f4-2079-4e1f-bad5-89f6269cd605) of Microsoft 365 apps for enterprise. For Excel 2016 please refer to "[Get & Transform in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/get-transform-in-excel-881c63c6-37c5-4ca2-b616-59e18d75b4de)"